# Play Framework dynamic ip application.conf

Tags: playframework, configuration

We have several projects, we are using play framework and Scala.

In each project we have an script for running the project for example `run.sh` would have the following code

```
activator "run 9013" -Duser.timezone=GMT
```

The problem is that in the application.conf we have this

```
app.otherapp1.url="http://localhost:9021/tasks"
app.otherapp2.url="http://localhost:9023/front-end"
```

If you are working only locally it goes perfectly, projects sometimes redirects to other projects and that is the problem. this is the description of the problem

Suppose you have 2 projects, the first one is front-end and the second one is tasks

If you are in another computer you will go to the url http://localhost:9023 which is front-end, but because you are in another computer, if front-end redirects to project tasks and you are on another computer you will not be able to get there because in the application.conf you setted up localhost.

Does anyone knows if it is possible to set dynamic IP in the application.conf

It would be nice if when we are developing, each project could set up dynamically the ip of the computer that is running the project

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly but if you want to deploy applications on different ports, when launching your application, you can pass the port on the command line and do

```
./activator start -Dhttp.port=yourDynamicPort
```

as Kris suggests you can do

```
-Dhttp.address=yourIP
```

to assign address

Comment: ... and you can do the same with the IP address. Just use `-Dhttp.address=1.2.3.4`.

Comment: @John thank you for the answer I will edit my question

Comment: @Kris thank you for your answer but I will edit my question